# VBA Macro for PowerPoint - Find/replace Text and Change Paragraph Color

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to create a macro for the notes in a PowerPoint.

I need to search for a work (aka "tip") - when I find it, I need to change the word to ALL CAPS (aka TIP) and change the entire paragraph to red.

If the paragraph in the notes doesn't have the word - then it needs to stay black.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use a VBA macro for this.  But you need to try something out *first*, then post back with your code and a specific problem.  Here's a good place to start: http://youpresent.co.uk/slide-notes-text-file-vba/